# Nested resource form paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

this is my form

```
<%= form_for([@game,@message_template]) do |f| %>
```

and in my controller I do this:

```
def edit
  @message_template = MessageTemplate.find(params[:id])
  @game = Game.where(:slug => params[:game_id])
end
```

My route is like this `/games/:game_id/message_templates/:id`

But I am getting this

> undefined method `model_name' for #

Comment: are you sure you're getting both a game AND a message_template instance into their respective variables in that action?

Comment: yeah they are both in there, i'm using friendly_id would that affect the path? i tried manually typing the path helper but it only worked for post and not put.

Comment: POST and PUT will be different actions (create and update) respectively. So you'll have to query for your object(s) again in those actions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting that arel search to return the first object (for @game).

```
def edit
  @message_template = MessageTemplate.find(params[:id])
  @game = Game.where(:slug => params[:game_id]).first
end
```

routes.rb:

```
#based on your comment, this will give you all (and likely more) of the paths you will need.
resources :games do
  resources :message_templates
end
```

Comment: I've added what should likely be in your routes, based on your comment in your original post.  Also, if you are not getting an error but nothing is showing, ensure you're rendering the correct template which should likely be in "app/views/message_templates/edit.?

Comment: this now gives me `undefined method `message_templates_path'` I had `resources :message_templates, :on => :member` before.

Comment: Are you using that path helper (message_templates_path) in your template(s)? If so, and since this is a nested resource it will now be game_message_templates_path(@game) -- since message_templates are nested under game(s). Use rake:routes to see all of the routes and helpers this created for you.

Comment: replace it with the nested route helper(s) as I've mentioned above.

Comment: You've got more problems than your original question which has been answered: your action was returning an ActiveRecord::Relation object and not the "game" object you were expecting. Unfortunately this isn't the place to continue to debug the rest of your issues as it won't be helpful for anyone with a similar problem. I'd suggest posting another question with your new issue.